# Vertically centering an element with display: inline-block

Tags: css

I have the following structure inside my nav:

```
ul > ((li>a) * 2)
```

the css for the elements is:

```
ul {height: 29px; list-style: none;}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 23px;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

How do I vertically center the li's within the ul?
Thanks!
**EDIT:** the a element is a child of the li element.

Answer (score 0):

If you heights are fixed, the easiest solution is to give the `li` a top-margin of 3px.

Alternative:

```
ul {
  height: 26px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`line-height: 29px` on the `li`'s should work **if** the text is all on one line

```
ul {
  height: 50px; 
  background: #eee; 
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    line-height: 50px; /* same as UL height */
}
```